# How does one get around the missing sync agent problem in Mavericks to sync with Outlook?

Tags: icloud, ms-office, calendar

How does one get around the missing sync agent problem in Mavericks to sync with Outlook?

If one tries to sync calendars or contacts through Itunes or with Outlook there is a whole part of the OS that is missing that was always there till Mountain Lion. It seems that Mavericks is missing many important bits. It seems that they thought that syncing with I cloud would be the answer. That is completely inadequate with people who do not live in first world areas.

How do we get around this lack of a vendor supplied sync since Office doesn't provide one either that works with Mavericks and the native contact and calendar data on OS X?

Comment: I removed the iTunes tag and tried to edit this for grammar. Are you looking to perform a two way sync of data from OS X address book to the contact store of a specific version of MS Outlook on Mac (and the same for calendars)? Clearly the MS "solution" is to pay for Office 365 and the Apple "solution" is to use iCloud for free, but you have a valid point of not wanting to sync over network if it is error prone or costly to get to the cloud in the first place.